# conv2 in octave showing a white image

Tags: image-processing, octave, convolution

I am using conv2 to perform convolution on a gray image. conv2 was returning a floating value so I performed floor operation on it.

The input image is:

[image: InputImage]

The code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
img = imread("balloonGrayNoisy.jpg");
z = ones(3, 3);
newImg = floor( conv2(img, z/9) );

for i = 1:size(newImg, 1)
  for j = 1: size(newImg, 2)
    if(newImg(i,j) > 255)
      disp(newImg(i, j))
    endif
  endfor
endfor

imshow(newImg)
```

Where img is the image read. When I output the newImg, It shows a blank image:

[image: OutputImage]

The loop is to ensure the values are in range. Inface, they are, but I don't know why am I not getting the output.

Comment: Instead of flooring your image, cast it to `uint8`. Type `double` images are expected to have a range `[0..1]`

Comment: I am new to this field, but I think for b/w images the pixel intensity should be from 0..255.

Comment: b/w image (1bit) in Matlab/Octave is logical type.

Comment: Grayscale images can either be `uint8` with a range `[0..255]` or a floating-point type with range `[0..1)`.

Comment: Sorry for the problem caused. The image is grey and not b/w.  I will update the post.

Comment: What should I do now? I am still not getting the output.

Comment: If you've made the suggested changes and they still didn't work for you, you should post a [mre] including your input image and the minimal code required to reproduce your problem. Please note that since there more than 2 people commenting, you'll need to tag the person you're responding to (like @beaker) in order for them to be notified.

Comment: @beaker I had made the necessary changes.

Comment: So, you didn't try what I suggested. If I run your code, I get a white image. If I change the last line to `imshow(uint8(newImg))`, I get the expected image.

Comment: @beaker No. I tried it , but I was running from cmd.  The code I used was newImg = unit8( conv2(img, z/9) ); I didn't tried the way you did. Anyway, Thanks for your help.

Comment: That way worked for me as well. Don't know why it didn't for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216516/discussion-between-neel-rayal-and-beaker).